# Different font family for different OS

Tags: fonts, font-family

I would like to have HelveticaNeue as the first family for mac, and Roboto for PC. Is it possible??

Or is there any media query that detects windows??

Thanks

Comment: What is the context for your question? Are you referring to a web browser and CSS? If so, please adjust your question and tags to reflect that.

Comment: have your server send over a different file when your sitefonts.css is requested by a client, based on the user agent? That said, using Roboto for "PC" (which one? Windows? Linux? BSD? Raspberry Pi?), which is only a font common to Android and maybe the Chromebook, is a weird choice.